# supremum of the set T={n∈ℕ: 1/2^n ≤1}.

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

$T=\{n\in\mathbb ℕ: \frac1{2^n} \leq 1\}$

I worked this question and for the supremum i got $\frac{1}{2}$ because $0<\frac{1}{2^n}\leq \frac12$....Is the question even correct in the first place? May you have your analysis on this one.
The question was to state if it is true that $\sup (T)=1$.Is the question even correct in the first place?

If in the set of upper bounds the set $B=\{\frac12,1,\dots\}$ we have $\frac12$ as the smallest element how come $\sup(T)=1$?

Comment: There's something off about this question. As it stands, $T = \{n \in \Bbb{N} : 1/2^n \le 1\}$ sounds like the set of all natural numbers $n$ with the property that $1/2^n \le 1$, which is *all* natural numbers! That is, it sounds like $T = \Bbb{N}$, which has no upper bound! Did you mean $\{1/2^n : 1/2^n \le 1 \text{ and } n \in \Bbb{N}\}$ instead?

Comment: Please read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for future reference.

Comment: The question is exactly as I stated it.I think you made a good point, I think by mathematical induction if I prove T=N...Then the statement is false T has no supremum

Comment: The question is exactly as I stated it.I think you made a good point, I think by mathematical induction if I prove T=N...Then the statement is false T has no supremum

Answer (score 1):

The supremum of the set $T$, as you wrote it, does not exist. This is because $T=\mathbb N$, because the inequality $\frac{1}{2^n}\leq 1$ is true for every element $n\in\mathbb N$.

---

Note that I answered the question you **wrote**, but probably not the one you *wanted* to write. But I can't read your mind. So if you discover that the answer is not what you needed, edit your question, and I will gladly look at it again.

Comment: Your argument is convincing....Maybe I should ask.... If we had T={n∈ℕ:1/2^n}....Would we have a sup in this case?

Comment: Like I said, no. If $T=\{n\in\mathbb N: \frac{1}{2^n} \leq 1\}$, then $T=\mathbb N$, and therefore, $\sup(T)$ does not exist.

Comment: my question is after removing the inequality....Please check how I changed the set

Comment: @Leornard The expression $\left\{n\in\mathbb N: \frac{1}{2^n}\right\}$ is nonsensical. A definition of a set has the form $\{x| P(x)\}$ where $P$ is some statement about $x$. This means that $P(x)$ can be true or false, depending on what $x$ is. If "$P(n)$"  is equal to "$\frac{1}{2^n} \leq 1$", then $P(n)$ can indeed be true or false, so it can be used in defining a set. If, on the other hand, "$P(n)$" is equal to "$\frac{1}{2^n}$", then we cannot speak of $P(n)$ being either true or false, so we cannot use $P(n)$ in defining a set.

Comment: The main focus is not on whether P(n) is true. I am responding specifically to the last sentence...The question is would the set then have a supremum if we removed the inequality. For instance if one needs to find if this set K={n∈ℕ:2+1/n} is bounded . We can use our knowledge of natural numbers to deduce that K is bounded below and above because 0<1/n≤1 hence 2<1+1/n≤3  ∀ n∈ℕ and thus all x in K SHOULD SATISFY 2<x≤3

Comment: @Leornard The main focus is that $P(n)$ must have a truth value. It can be false, or it can be true, but it must be *one of those things*. If it is not, then $\{n\in\mathbb N:P(n)\}$ **is not a valid definition of a set**. So we cannot speak about whether $K$ is bounded or not, because you did not provide a valid definition for $K$. You might be speaking of the set $\{2+\frac{1}{n}| n\in\mathbb N\}$, which is indeed bounded.